# How do I insert unicode into MS-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, unicode, internationalization

I want to insert info.NativeName into a nvarchar field in the database.
It doesn't work, all I get is ??????? where the encoding is not western/latin.

Outputting listcultures directly in an asp.net website on page_onload worked fine, but it seems not to work via database.

```
Public Sub listcultures()
    'Dim x As System.DateTime = DateTime.Now
    'Response.Write(x.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss MMM d', 'yyy 'PST'", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CN", False)))
    Dim info As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    For Each info In System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)
        'Response.Write("Deutsch: " + info.DisplayName + " English: " + info.EnglishName + " Native: " + info.NativeName + " Name: " + info.Name + " Codepage: " + info.TextInfo.ANSICodePage.ToString() + "<br />")

        'InsertData(info.DisplayName, info.EnglishName, info.NativeName, info.Name, info.TextInfo.ANSICodePage.ToString(), info.IsNeutralCulture.ToString())

        If Not info.IsNeutralCulture Then
            'item.SubItems.Add(amount.ToString("C", info.NumberFormat))
            'item.SubItems.Add(dateNow.ToString("d", info.DateTimeFormat))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? I suppose something with encoding ?

Comment: This code only contains a loop over comments. What does InsertData do? Please show the CREATE TABLE statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add N before the unicode string when you are inserting it. [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-us)

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh. INSERT N'MyString' instead of INSERT 'MyString'.   N as in u-Nicode. Thanks !

Comment: For this to have fixed the problem indicates that the OP is not parameterizing the TSQL; which indicates (IMO) a **far** *bigger* problem...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: True, but I only use it localy to create a database of localized strings. It won't be in any public code, so there is no danger of SQL injection, and besides, I always replace the ' with ''. I've seen the N' before, but I didn't know it stands for unicode.

Comment: @Quandry - OK then; as long as you are in control of that data, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happens? Ultimately you are just building a string here and storing into `nvarchar`, so it *should* work fine, provided:

- you have correctly parametrized the input to the command
- you haven't overflown the width of the the column

We can't really say more without seeing `InsertData`, which I **assume** talks to the database. I'm also not *quite* sure why a "list" method would be doing inserts in the first place, of course. Plus since everything is commented out at the moment, I would *expect* nothing to happen...

Comment: Well, list is just the loop, the insert happens in InsertData, which is commented out here, but I of course ran it without commenting it out. I wouldn't have gotten ????? values, in combination with correct english values, if the insert wouldn't have worked.